# Python requests using public ip instead of proxy

Tags: python, python-requests

Python requests seems to be using public ip instead of proxy even after i provide the `proxies` argument

```py
import requests
resp = requests.get("https://ifconfig.me", proxies={"http": "3.113.20.21:3128"})
print(resp.text)
```

Gives me my public ip `122.161.75.8` instead of `3.113.20.21`

while using curl with the same proxy works

```bash
curl --proxy "http://3.113.20.21:3128" "https://ifconfig.me/"
```

gives `3.113.20.21`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
resp = requests.get("https://ifconfig.me", proxies={"http": "3.113.20.21:3128"})
```

There are multiple kinds of proxies. There are HTTP proxies, and HTTPS proxies. HTTP proxies won't be used for HTTPS requests.

The [documentation](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/#proxies) has an example of how to set up a proxy which is used for both HTTP and HTTPS.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @NickODell for specifying by default requests won't use `http proxy` for `https requests`

To change use

```py
import requests

proxies = {
 'http': 'http://3.113.20.21:3128',
 'https': 'http://3.113.20.21:3128',
}

resp = requests.get('https://ifconfig.me', proxies=proxies)
print(resp.text)
```

Gives `3.113.20.21`